# Upload image from camera or gallery to FirebaseStorage

Tags: android, firebase-authentication, firebase-storage

I have the following code in order to display an image inside `ImageView` once I choose from gallery/took a picture:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == this.RESULT_CANCELED) {
        return;
    }
    if (requestCode == GALLERY) {
        if (data != null) {
            Uri contentURI = data.getData();
            try {
                FixBitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), contentURI);
                ShowSelectedImage.setImageBitmap(FixBitmap);

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(ProfileActivity.this, "Failed!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }

    } else if (requestCode == CAMERA) {
        FixBitmap = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
        ShowSelectedImage.setImageBitmap(FixBitmap);
    }
}
```

Now, I had like this image to be saved inside my FirebaseStorage under the `uid` of the current user.

So I know I should use something as:

```
String userUid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
```

However, how do I make this upload inside my storage? My final goal is that once the user login it will automatically display the profile picture from the storage and if there is no picture or the user took a new pic, it will update the one inside the storage.

I had problems also with type since `putBytes` required `BytesArray` and the results I had are `Bitmap` or so.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following code will help you to store image under images folder with userid of current user. You have image location so Firebase will pick image from storage.

```
uploadImg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(contentURI != null) {

            StorageReference childRef = storageRef.child("/images/"+uid+".jpg");

            //uploading the image
            UploadTask uploadTask = childRef.putFile(contentURI);
            uploadTask.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Upload successful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Upload Failed -> " + e, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
        }
        else {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Select an image", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
});
```

Declare variable :

```
StorageReference storageRef;
```

and in onCreateView :

```
storageRef = storage.getReference();
```

Make it publicly declared or it will throw an error again

Comment: I keep getting the following error: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference.child(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference

Comment: did you assign `storageRef` ? it is storage ref of firebase

Comment: I have: FirebaseStorage storage; StorageReference storageRef; then inside onCreate I have storageRef = storage.getReference(); and my corrent error is :Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference com.google.firebase.storage.FirebaseStorage.getReference()' on a null object reference

Comment: then what is problem ?

Comment: Sorry, had to update to implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:17.0.0'